# Frontend AJAX call to API is not showing all properties of returned object

Tags: c#, ajax, ecmascript-6, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an unusual problem.

I am making an AJAX request to my backend API.

The API is simple and just returns an array of objects like this....

API:

```
    [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var objects = NightSkyObjectList.GetAllObjects(location);
        return Ok(Map(objects));
    }
```

My frontend calls this API, and creates an object variable for each returned object like you see here:

Front End:

```
return $.ajax("/api/astronomy/, {
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(response, status, XHR) {
        var calObj = [];
        $.each(response, function(index, skyObject){
            var object = {
                id: skyObject.id,
                galaxyId: skyObject.galaxyId,
                solarSystem: skyObject.solarSystem,
                objName: skyObject.objectName,
                galaxy: skyObject.galaxy,
                objType: skyObject.type  
            };
            console.log("Object JSON Data: ", object);
            calObj.push(object);
        });
    }
```

The problem is, the property called, galaxy, is always undefined in the frontend.

I put a break-point in visual studio right when the API returns the data, and I do see the 'galaxy' object.

But when I do a console.log in the front-end, I see everything else, but the galaxy object is always undefined.

I'm at a loss here, because I can't figure out how else to debug or what is happening to the galaxy.

Is there anything else I can do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Map function is not mapping the galaxy object.

You can try see if Galaxy object is being populate removing it from Ok function and given it to a variable, after that you must place a breakpoint and see if the object is null or not, example:

```
 [HttpGet()]
 public IActionResult Get()
 {
    var objects = NightSkyObjectList.GetAllObjects(location);
    var mapResponse = Map(objects); //Place your breakpoint here and take a look if Map is returning the galaxy object
    return Ok(mapResponse);
 }
```